# Any OBJC API to get access to the Exchange Source of the AddressBook on Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, exchange-server, addressbook

The language I am using is Objective-C, and I'd like to get the exchange source list from the address book on Mac.

When using addressBook.framework for the iOS platform, I can found some API like:

```
CFArrayRef allSources = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllSources(book);
```

This works perfectly, but I can't find any similar API in the same framework for Mac.

Is there any way to get the source list from mac?

Or are there any libraries or frameworks that contain the functions?

Comment: You may be looking for `CFArrayRef allGroups = ABCopyArrayOfAllGroups;`. For more info on that, check out the documentation here: <https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/AddressBook/C/ABAddressBookRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001526-CH1g-F18575>. The only problem with that is, I don't know if a group is on the Mac what a source is in iOS.

Comment: I've tried this API, but it only returns the groups under the sources. And when I try to get their "parentGroups", it just returns an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked the Apple's Document, it seems there's no way to get ExchangeSource data on the Mac, thanks anyway!